# How to get VSCode to recognize Kotlin classes in Java code?

Tags: java, class, kotlin, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm using VSCode. I have the following in `myApi.kt`:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.myapi

data class MyClass(
    val accountNumber: String,
    val state: String,
    val country: String
)
```

...and I have the following in `myApp.java`:

```
import com.mycompany.myproject.myapi.*;

MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

Compilation and execution are all fine. The only problem is VSCode gives me a red squigly underline beneath references to `MyClass` in the java file. Hovering over it, it says:

> MyClass cannot be resolved to a type Java(16777218)

I have the [Kotlin plug-in](https://github.com/mathiasfrohlich/vscode-kotlin) installed in VSCode.

How can I get VSCode to recognize this Kotlin class in my java file?

Comment: This is not yet supported based on this open issue https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/531

Comment: Thanks, @Barry. Go ahead and put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: OK. @Jonathan I've done that.

Comment: This is super frustrating, vscode works well while debuging using a kotlin configuration but errors on importing kotlin classes on java are a big down. In the other way debugging kotlin and java with intelliJ does not work when using WSL2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet supported based on this open [issue](http://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/531)

Comment: There is a PR open to resolve the issue, so help may be on the way: https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/pull/334